# mediawiki unable to upload files, but no errors

Tags: mediawiki

I have a 64-bit, CentOS 6.4 server running Apache 2 and MediaWiki 1.21.2 (upgraded from a 1.19 install from another server, but the problem did not exist there).

The problem is that users cannot upload new files to the server and I'm not getting any error messages, either from apache or from php. When I use the upload form, it just refreshes the page.

LocalSettings.php has the uploads enabled:

```
$wgEnableUploads = true;
$wgUseImageMagick = true;
$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";
```

php.ini has uploads turned on and error messages turned on:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = On
html_errors = On
```

selinux is disabled (server is not public-facing)

The entire mediawiki directories are owned by the apache user, the images directory is chmod to 777 and the /tmp directory is also chmod to 777.

I don't know what else to try at this point. If anyone has an idea about this, I'd be grateful. Even just a way to output an error would be great.

Comment: It's possible mediawiki is turning off display errors despite your ini settings. You should also check error logs if display errors is all you're relying on.

Comment: I set the error_log var in the php.ini and tried again, but there was still no output. Thanks for the suggestion all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out (and I feel a right fool for not noticing sooner). There was a typo in the $wgServer setting in LocalSettings.php where it was using the server name instead of the base URL.

As I mentioned before, the wiki had been moved from another server. While the new server was being tested, I'd changed the name so I could access the site without mucking with the current   setup and, unfortunately, forgot to update it to the real URL when the wiki was finally moved and the DNS updated.

TL;DR, The uploads were being redirected into oblivion. They never made it to the server for processing, so no log messages.

In my defense the server's name and the URL are only off by two characters. Teaches me to be more thorough with my migration documentation.